# Заполнение массива - PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите как в массив `children` записать `parent_id` , сейчас у меня переписывает его просто

```
function build_tree($cats,$parent_id,$children){
    if(is_array($cats) and count($cats[$parent_id])>0){
        $tree = '<div class="item-children">';
        $count = 0;
         foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
            $count = $count + 1;
            $coountt = $cat['parent_id'];
            $tree .= '<div class="item-child">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="item-parent">';
            $tree .= '<div class="item-data" data-user="'.$cat['user_id'].'">
                            <img src="https://storytsa.com/attach/user/images/1490332239.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="span">'.$cat['user_id'].' - '.$count.' -id записи = '.$cat['id'].'</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
            $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id'],$children);
            $tree .= '
                </div>
            </div>
            ';         
         }
         if ($count < 2) {$children[] = $parent_id; echo 'mensche - '.$count.' user - '.$parent_id.' </br>';}
        $tree .= '</div>';

     } 
     else {return '0 child user - '.$parent_id.' </br>';$children[] = $parent_id;}      
     return $tree; 
}
echo build_tree($cats,2,$children);
```

Comment: По сслылке передавай массив

Comment: это как? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `function build_tree ($cats, $parent_id, &$children) {`

Comment: выдает ошибку Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /var/www/u0529038/data/www/colibri.im/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/54.include.cache.php on line 25

Comment: Вы добавили ссылку в декларировании функции?) Потому что ошибка говорит про то, что вы вставили её при вызове

Comment: сюда добавил function build_tree ($cats, $parent_id, &$children) {, но не идет заполнение массива

Comment: У вас добавление в массив, после **return**) Я бы рекоммендовал использовать какую-то IDE (например PHPStorm https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download), они обычно подсвечивают синтаксис и облегчают поиск подобных ошибок

Comment: как массив обработать вне функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$children = [
  'demo' => 'value',
];

//Передача массива по ссылке в функцию
function build_tree(&$children) {
    $children['demo'] = 'value2';
}

print_r($children);
build_tree($children);
$children['demo2'] = 'value3';
print_r($children);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Функция построения дерева из массива от Tommy Lacroix
function getTree($dataset) {
    $tree = array();

    foreach ($dataset as $id => &$node) {    
        //Если нет вложений
        if (!$node['parent']){
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        }else{ 
            //Если есть потомки то перебераем массив
            $dataset[$node['parent']]['childs'][$id] = &$node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Да у человека не с рекурсией проблемма а с опытом. Это его уже вторая попытка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856714

Comment: ну, там от выводить что-то пытался, тут записывать, мало ли может идет прогресс. Я правда не понимаю зачем он весь html код пишет внутри массива

Comment: Ну ему еще предстоит пройти разделение мух от котлет. Так гляди до MVС дойдет

Answer (score 0):

как массив children обработать вне функции?
выводит `Array ( )`

```
        $children = [];
function build_tree($cats,$parent_id,&$children){
    if(is_array($cats) and count($cats[$parent_id])>0){
        $count = 0;
         foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
            $count = $count + 1;
            build_tree($cats,$cat['id'],$children);
         }
         if ($count < 2) {$children[] = $parent_id; echo 'mensche - '.$count.' user - '.$parent_id.' </br>';}
     } 
     else {$children[] = $parent_id;echo '0 child user - '.$parent_id.' </br>';}      
}
echo build_tree($cats,2);
print_r($children);
```